# How to restrict lines of code in exception printStackTrace

Tags: java, exception, printstacktrace

```
try
{
 //logic
}
catch(Exception e)
{
      e.printStackTrace();
}
```

the printStackTrace() method will give us lines of statements related to exception but in which all lines are not useful for us

how we can restrict lines of exception details

Comment: You want the error message.... use `e.getMessage()` instead.

Comment: How should Java know what classes in the stack trace are relevant to you? If you want to manually check/print the stack trace use [`e.getStackTrace()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getStackTrace())

Answer (score 2):

You can write the stacktrace into a PrintWriter, then take the output of the writer, and restrict the number of bytes, or lines, or filter it with a regular expression, or whatever fits your needs.

```
} catch (Exception e) {
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(sw));
    String fullStackTrace = sw.toString();
    String restrictedStackTrace = ... //now you can manipulate the fullStackTrace
    System.err.print(restrictedStackTrace);
}
```